# Random number on Highcharts + AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm trying to create a chart that generates random numbers and it updates the maximum value after clicking on a button.

This is my controller:

```
$scope.max = 1;

$scope.randomNumber = function(max,min) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min));
  }
  return arr;
}

  $('#chart').highcharts({
    series: [{
      data: (function () {
        var data = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
          data.push({
            x: i,
            y: $scope.randomNumber($scope.max,0)[0]
          });
        }
        return data;
      }())
    }]
  });
```

And this is the HTML that should update the maximum value:

```
<button ng-click="max = 10">10</button>
<button ng-click="max = 100">100</button>
<button ng-click="max = 1000">1000</button>
<button ng-click="max = 10000">10000</button>
```

However, it's not updating the maximum value. Any tips?

Here's a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/N0UfORtSjYW5jaPGojXH?p=preview

Comment: I think your data array is incorrect, 'X' is a number while `Y` is an array. I changed `$scope.randomNumber($scope.max,0)` to `$scope.randomNumber($scope.max,0)[0]` and a chart was generated

Comment: Thanks, @Ronnie. It indeed generated the chart. However, I still have the other issue: it's not updating the `max` value when I click on the buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to redraw the chart when you change the max value.

See the plnkr I watch the max value and when max changes call the draw function.

```
  $scope.draw = function() {
    $('#chart').highcharts({
      series: [{
        data: (function() {
          var data = [];

          for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
            data.push({
              x: i,
              y: $scope.randomNumber($scope.max, 0)[0]
            });
          }
          return data;
        }())
      }]
    });
  }

  $scope.draw();

  $scope.$watch('max', function() {
    $scope.draw();
  });
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Cp0V46z7UgnRiQsKNrtl?p=preview